# Centralizers in free products of $p$-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

If $G_1,\dots,G_n$ are discrete groups, and $G=G_1 \ast G_2 \ast \dots \ast G_n$ is their free product, then for $g \in G_i$ sean as an element of $G$, it is clear the centralizer of $g$ in $G$ is just its centralizer in $G_i$: $Z_G(g)=Z_{G_i}(G)$.

When we replace in the above $G_1,\dots,G_n$ by pro-finite groups, and $G$ by their free product in the category of pro-finite groups, the same result is false, even when the $G_i$ are all $\mathbb Z$ so that $G$ is a pro-finite free group. This is explained in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62682/centralizers-of-elements-in-free-profinite-groups).

But I wonder:

> Is the analog result true for pro-$p$-groups?

That is: if $G_1,\dots,G_n$ are pro-$p$ groups, and $G=G_1 \ast G_2 \ast \dots \ast G_n$ is their free product in the category of pro-$p$-group, then for $g \in G_i$ sean as an element of $G$, is it true that the centralizer of $g$ in $G$ is just its centralizer in $G_i$: $Z_G(g)=Z_{G_i}(G)$? When the $G_i$, hence $G$ are free, this is true by a beautiful one-line argument given in comment by Barnea in the question cited above.

Comment: I just realize that some questions that seam related are 
addressed in the two letters from Jean-Pierre Serre to Leila Schneps
published in the book she co-edited "Geometric Galois Actions".


